Nextra docs theme - customize breakpoints
Context
We're using Nextra Docs Theme - Nextra for a documentation portal.
We want to change the breakpoint pixel value at which the layout changes to mobile.
The issue
The current (default) breakpoint for layout change to mobile is 768px. There's also another breakpoint at 1280px that changes the article > main width so that it uses the full available width.
We want to customize the breakpoints because with the default setting, the top menu flows into the site menu and search box becomes unreasonably small on viewports cca <1000px.
The goal
The goal is to change the mobile breakpoint so that viewports <1100px see mobile layout.
Attempted solutions
Official docs
I searched the docs - Theme Configuration - Nextra - to no avail, I don't see breakpoints mentioned there, neither have I found anything relevant in there or in other parts of Nextra docs.
Chat GPT
I asked ChatGPT - it says that Nextra uses TailWind with these breakpoints:

sm: 640px
md: 768px
lg: 1024px
xl: 1280px
2xl: 1536px

It then suggested to use npx tailwindcss init to create tailwind.config.js and put there the code below. I did this in the Nextra project root.
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'lg': '1200px', // Adjust to your preferred breakpoint
        // This means the mobile hamburger menu will trigger at a larger resolution.
      },
    },
  },
};

It makes no difference for me. I tried redefining all the breakpoints, to no avail. The mobile layout switch still happened at 768px.
ChatGPT also suggested another approach - overwrite the breakpoints in globals CSS like this:
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nextra-navbar {
    display: none; /* Hide the desktop navbar */
  }
  .nextra-mobile-menu {
    display: block; /* Show the mobile hamburger menu */
  }
}

I tried that, the classes are a bit different but I did manage to display the hamburger menu at 1100px, but I didn't manage to selectively hide the desktop left- and top-side navi and display the hamburger contents. I may be missing some elements here, but I don't know. It certainly doesn't feel like canonical approach. I'd like to avoid hacking the Nextra theme as much as possible.
Brave AI
Brave AI has some other suggestions but it fairly visible it has not much data to base its suggestions on.
Brave idea 01: theme.config.jsx
One proposal was to put the breakpoints definition into the theme.config.jsx (in Nextra project root). I liked this option the best, it's no hacking, it's canonical optimization...
export default {
  // ... other configurations ...
  breakpoints: {
    sm: 640, // small (e.g., mobile)
    md: 960, // medium (e.g., tablet)
    lg: 1280, // large (e.g., desktop)
    xl: 1920, // extra large (e.g., large desktop)
  },
};

... except it makes no difference, the mobile layout switch still happens on 768px viewport.
Brave idea 02: media queries
Another Brave's suggestion was, again, redefining the breakpoints using @media queries in global CSS (I have that in nextra-root/static):
@import '@material-ui/core/styles/overrides';

.breakpoints {
  @media (max-width: ${theme.breakpoints.sm}) {
    /* styles for small screens */
  }
  @media (min-width: ${theme.breakpoints.sm}) and (max-width: ${theme.breakpoints.md}) {
    /* styles for medium screens */
  }
  /* ... and so on for each breakpoint ... */
}

The issue is, I still don't know what to put into the media queries as I don't know what elements to show and hide there.
Brave idea 03: _meta.js
Another idea Brave had was to add a _meta.js with this content:
module.exports = {
  // ... other configurations ...
  breakpoints: {
    desktop: 1200px,
    tablet: 1000px,
    mobile: 900px, // updated mobile breakpoint
  },
};

I put the file into the Nextra root. The Nextra's server response for that was Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'breakpoints', so that's a no-go too.
And with that, I'm turning to you, community, for help. I'm pretty new to all things Next so I may be missing something obvious. I'm very grateful for your advice.

A colleague informed me that this is impossible without actually rewriting the theme. To quote their words, 'This is one of the "You chose Nextra, you have to live with Nextra" things.'
I'm keeping this question without an answer just in case anyone would come up with a viable solution in the future.
